# Serving images directly from GCS in GAE using Blobstore API and Images API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

Many questions and answers on Blobstore and Google Cloud Storage(GCS) are two or three years old, while things change dramatically these years. GCS is no longer a standalone service. It is [integrated](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/google-integration) into Google App Engine (GAE) now.

Google seems to push GCS so hard that [Blobstore is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore), for example,

> The Files API feature used here to write files to Blobstore has been
>   deprecated and is going to be removed at some time in the future, in
>   favor of writing files to Google Cloud Storage and using Blobstore to
>   serve them.

I believe it is high time to switch to GCS.

For example, `www.example.com` is a site built on GAE, while `example.jpg` is an image stored on GCS, I want to serve the image using the url `http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg`

This used to be impossible, but now it is possible thanks to the [integration](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/google-integration).

I found this:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/
says:

> When the Blobstore API is used together with the Images API, you get a
>   powerful way to serve images, because you can serve images directly
>   from GCS, bypassing the App Engine app, which saves on instance hour
>   costs.

I do know how to **'bypassing the App Engine app'**. Is there any example on how to bypass GAE while serving the images using Blobstore API and Images API?

Answer (score 3):

Instructions are here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url

Start with an image hosted in Google Cloud Storage.

First, use the Blobstore API's create_gs_key() function to generate a blob key for your GCS image object. Then, pass that blob key into the Image API's get_serving_url() function.

The Image API will give you a special URL that skips over your app engine app and serves the image directly.

Comment: Thanks but it turns out that the link it generates is something like http://lh4.ggpht.com/TgjDT-cPRr6bjrpSVQeILk93o4Ouzjo1ygMB6KpmnCHhyH5vJKKRrqxCD2bC3T09CRIP6h5QFsV_l0hnhio5bN7z It is not what I want. I need to serve the image using my own custom domain url like http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg If Blobstore is deprecated, this seems impossible in GAE.

Comment: If you have a domain is a CNAME'd Google Cloud Storage bucket, like "images.example.com", you could serve them directly from Google Cloud Storage as images.example.com/example.jpg.

You cannot, however, use "www.example.com" both for app engine as well as for google cloud storage.

Comment: Great, but is there any way to serve the content other than images, say Video or Audio, this way by skipping app engine and directly serving from GCS?

Comment: @HarshalPatil You want to look at Access Control Lists (ACLs).
Yes, it is possible for you to assign a bucket (directory) or object (image) to be publicly readable. You would want: "x-goog-acl: public-read"

Docs: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#defaultobjects

Answer (score 2):

You actually do not need to use BlobStore at all now.  The following will work to get the images API URL for serving images stored in GCS:

```
from google.appengine.api import images

images.get_serving_url(None, filename='/gs/<bucket>/<object>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Serving images from 'www' is not a good idea if you are using www as you GAE Cname, to serve images you can create a new sub-domain.In our case we are using cdn.example.com, and we serve our images like http://cdn.example.com/images/example.jpg

How Do we do it.

create a GCS bucket with name cdn.example.com and place your images under /images path.

Specify your index and 404 pages and it will be good to go.

more on this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration?hl=en