# GAE + Blobstore: Serve different image size depending on viewport width

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-app-engine, blobstore

As we know, we can serve images from the blobstore using its *serving url*, and append `=sXX` to indicate the image's width:

```
<!-- serving an image of 600px width -->
<img src="{{serving_url}}=s600" alt=""/>
```

This works well, except we want to serve a smaller image for smaller screens for obvious webperf reasons. How can we serve a different image width depending on screen size?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull this off easily using javascript, the basic technique is to change the `src` attribute after evaluating the media queries you're interested in.

For starters, I would avoid filling the `src` of the image until evaluation, so the full image doesn't load by default; something like this:

```
<img data-src="{{serving_url}}" height="240" width="320">
```

Here we rendered the url in a data attribute so we have access to it later in the script. I'm also adding a default size so the space is reserved, but that's optional of course.

Now, we can use [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to evaluate our query strings:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 667px)')
if (mql.matches) {
    // we're probably running on an iPhone6!
    img.src = img.dataset.src + '=s667'
}
```

The image is fetched using the perfect size!

I'm including a working snippet, it can be easily extended for many query tests for you to try.

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img')
  , mql = window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 667px)')
  , size = 1200
if (mql.matches) {
    size = 667
}
img.src = img.dataset.src + '=s' + size
```

```css
img {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<img
    data-src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/TgjDT-cPRr6bjrpSVQeILk93o4Ouzjo1ygMB6KpmnCHhyH5vJKKRrqxCD2bC3T09CRIP6h5QFsV_l0hnhio5bN7z"
    height="240"
    width="320"
    >
```

The test image was kindly "provided" by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051789/serving-images-directly-from-gcs-in-gae-using-blobstore-api-and-images-api). I'm also using [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) because it makes sense (to me).